# Forbid row insertion | no jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dynamic table. Data comes from inputs by Create button click.
If at least one row includes current input ID-field value (not inserted yet) program should forbid row insertion.
I tried to add checkId() logic but it didn't work for me:

```
    checkId = () => {
    var isDuplicate = false;
    var idVal = inputs[0].value;

    if (textbox.value.includes(idVal)){
        isDuplicate = true;
        row.remove();
        alert("Pease, enter unique ID")

    }
    return isDuplicate;
}
```

Is there any way to implement this logic within existing code (no jQuery)?

Here are both html and js:

```js
let headerArr = new Array();
headerArr = ['ID', 'Fname', 'Lname', 'Age'];
//console.log(headerArr.length)

//inputs
var div = document.getElementById('enter');
var inputs = div.getElementsByTagName('input')
var count = 0;

createTable = () => {

  let storage = document.createElement('table');
  storage.setAttribute('id', 'storage'); //set the table ID

  let row = storage.insertRow(-1);

  for (let h = 0; h < headerArr.length; h++) { //table header
    let headCols = document.createElement('th');
    headCols.innerHTML = headerArr[h];
    row.appendChild(headCols);
  }

  let div = document.getElementById('dynamicTable');
  div.appendChild(storage); //add the table to the page
}

/* checkId = () => {
 var isDuplicate = false;
 var idVal = inputs[0].value;
 //textbox = document.createElement('input')
 
 if (textbox.value.includes(idVal)){
  isDuplicate = true;
  row.remove();
  alert("Pease, enter unique ID")
  
 }
 return isDuplicate;
 
} */

//add a new row to the table
addEnd = () => {

  let table = document.getElementById('storage');

  var rowCount = table.rows.length; //get table row count
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount)

  var textbox;
  // if((!checkId()) && rowCount > 1){
  for (let c = 0; c <= headerArr.length - 1; c++) {
    var cell = document.createElement('td');
    cell = row.insertCell(c);

    textbox = document.createElement('input');
    textbox.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    textbox.setAttribute('readonly', true);

    textbox.setAttribute('value', inputs[c].value);

    cell.appendChild(textbox);

  }
  // } 
}

let createBtn = document.getElementById('create-btn');
createBtn.addEventListener('click', addEnd, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Table</title>

  <style>
  table {
      width: 100px;
      border-spacing: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid gray;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      padding: 2px 3px;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .enter {
      display: block;
      float: right;
      margin-bottom: 10px
    }
  }
  </style>

</head>

<body onload="createTable()">
  <div id="dynamicTable"></div>

  <div id="enter" class="enter">
    <p>ID:<br>
      <input class="enter__id" type="text" id="id"></input>
      <br>
      <p>First name:<br>
        <input class="enter__name type=" text " id="name "></input>
 <br>
 <p>Last name:<br>
 <input class="enter__surname type="text" id="surname"></input>
        <br>
        <p>Age:<br>
          <input class="enter__age" type="text" id="age"></input>
          <br>
          <button id="create-btn">Create</button>
          <button id="update-btn">Update</button>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Please, help me to find the right way to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (textbox.value.includes(idVal))
```

Your condition isn't valid, because you try to get .value from a variable that is undefined in your context.

I fix your js code :

```
       let headerArr = new Array();
    headerArr = ['ID', 'Fname', 'Lname', 'Age'];
    //console.log(headerArr.length)

    //inputs
    var div = document.getElementById('enter');
    var inputs = div.getElementsByTagName('input')
    var count = 0;

    createTable = () => {

        let storage = document.createElement('table');
        storage.setAttribute('id', 'storage'); //set the table ID

        let row = storage.insertRow(-1);

        for (let h = 0; h < headerArr.length; h++) { //table header
            let headCols = document.createElement('th');
            headCols.innerHTML = headerArr[h];
            row.appendChild(headCols);
        }

        let div = document.getElementById('dynamicTable');
        div.appendChild(storage); //add the table to the page
    }

    checkId = () => {

        var idVal = inputs[0].value;

        for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('id_cells').length; i++) {
            let el_id = document.getElementsByClassName('id_cells');
            if (el_id.value = idVal) {
                alert("Pease, enter unique ID");
                return true
            }

        }
        return false;

    }

    //add a new row to the table
    addEnd = () => {

        let table = document.getElementById('storage');

        var rowCount = table.rows.length; //get table row count
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount)

        if ((!checkId()) && rowCount > 1) {
            for (let c = 0; c <= headerArr.length - 1; c++) {
                var cell = document.createElement('td');
                cell = row.insertCell(c);

                textbox = document.createElement('input');
                textbox.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                textbox.setAttribute('readonly', true);

                textbox.setAttribute('value', inputs[c].value);
                if (c == 0) {
                    textbox.setAttribute('class', 'id_cells');
                }
                cell.appendChild(textbox);

            }
        }
    }

    let createBtn = document.getElementById('create-btn');
    createBtn.addEventListener('click', addEnd, false);
```

When you create your cells, if it's the first of the row (where the id should be displayed), I add a class to the cell to keep a reference. When you need to check for duplicate id, you get all the tag with the class i set beforehand and check their id in a loop.

I hope it solved your issue

Comment: Arthur Liger, thank you! Code modification you suggested really helped me to avoid duplication.